# How do you make a canvas change size when resizing and remove side bar?

Tags: javascript, html, game-development, window-resize

There might also be other issues but I'm just trying to make a platformer in JavaScript, if you have any solutions thank you so much!

If this is something I could have researched on my own please let me know about it as I am not great at JavaScript and normally look at google for answers.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var render = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width;
var height;
width = window.innerWidth;
height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style.left = "0px";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.absolute = "0px";

window.onresize = function() {
    var width;
    var height;
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
}

function rectangle(x, y, w, h) {
    render.beginPath();
    render.rect(x, y, w, h);
    render.fill();
    render.stroke();
}

function fillColor(r, g, b) {
    r = String(r);
    g = String(g);
    b = String(b);
    render.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

function strokeColor(r, g, b) {
    r = String(r);
    g = String(g);
    b = String(b);
    render.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

function strokeSize(size) {
    render.lineWidth = String(size);
}

function background(r, g, b) {
    fillColor(r, g, b);
    rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
}

background(25, 25, 25);
fillColor(0, 123, 0);
strokeColor(0, 0, 123);
strokeSize(6);
rectangle(25, 25, 50 , 50);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a function bound to `window.onresize` which gets `width` and `height` variables, but you never use that to actually change the canvas size. By the way, since you create new `width` and `height` vars within that function, you override the global scope `width` and `height` variables.

Comment: Get rid of the scrollbars by removing the margin from the body. CSS: `body{margin: 0;}`

Comment: Would I remove the variables in the `window.onresize`

Comment: If your intention is to update your global variables, then yes, you should not redeclare `var width; var height` inside that function. However, just updating those variables will not change your canvas size. You then have to separately call `canvas.width = ...` and `canvas.height = ...` again.

Comment: Yes, the CSS bit goes inside style tags (or a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssfile.css"/>`)

Comment: So
`<style>
body {
margin: 0;
}
</style>`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That will remove the scrollbars.

Comment: `window.onresize = function() {
 width = window.innerWidth;
 height = window.innerHeight;
 canvas.canvas.style.width = width + "px";
 canvas.canvas.style.height = height + "px";
}`

Comment: Sorry that was messy

Comment: Correct. Be aware you have to redraw the canvas contents when you resize the canvas as well.

Comment: Can you demonstrate?

Comment: The sidebar is still there yet again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer version of the comment chain from above.

To remove the scrollbars, add the following CSS, which removes the margin from the window. You have extra white space surrounding the canvas as well, which you can either remove, or make irrelevant with `font-size: 0;`

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

To resize the canvas, firstly remove the redeclaration of the width and height vars inside the onresize function, add the actual resizing code:

```
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

And finally, redraw the contents of the canvas after resize, since resizing clears the canvas. As a side note, updating the canvas size by using style attributes will not clear the canvas, but it will stretch it and the results are usually undesirable.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var render = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width;
var height;
width = window.innerWidth;
height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style.left = "0px";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.absolute = "0px";

window.onresize = function() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    
    background(25, 25, 25);
    fillColor(0, 123, 0);
    strokeColor(0, 0, 123);
    strokeSize(6);
    rectangle(25, 25, 50 , 50);
}

function rectangle(x, y, w, h) {
    render.beginPath();
    render.rect(x, y, w, h);
    render.fill();
    render.stroke();
}

function fillColor(r, g, b) {
    r = String(r);
    g = String(g);
    b = String(b);
    render.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

function strokeColor(r, g, b) {
    r = String(r);
    g = String(g);
    b = String(b);
    render.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

function strokeSize(size) {
    render.lineWidth = String(size);
}

function background(r, g, b) {
    fillColor(r, g, b);
    rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
}

background(25, 25, 25);
fillColor(0, 123, 0);
strokeColor(0, 0, 123);
strokeSize(6);
rectangle(25, 25, 50 , 50);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yet the sidebar is still there, is their a way to fix it?

Comment: White space is the problem there. I updated my answer. `font-size:0` will fix that.